# Correct way to break on time loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Not sure if this locks up the computer and cannot seem to activate range B1 all the time

```
Sub AutoRun_All_Coins()

Dim A           As Integer 
Dim Run_Times   As Integer

       Run_Times = Range("B2")

       For A = 1 To Run_Times
           Call AutoRun_GetHistoryBySymbol
           Call AutoRun_Copy2
           Call AutoRun_Copy_Buy_Matches
           Call AutoRun_Copy_Sell_Matches
           Call Autorun_Seperate_Trades
           Call AutoRun_Move_New_Trades
           Call AutoRun_Buy
           Call AutoRun_Sell

       Next A     

       Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 22 Range("B1").Activate
       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "AutoRun_Timer"
       Range("B1").Activate

End Sub

Sub AutoRun_Timer()

       Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 0       
       If Range("B1") = "" Then
            Call AutoRun_All_Coins 
       End If

End Sub
```

Have to click or double click B1 to get into it, maybe just a slow computer but is something going on in the background that I'm missing

Comment: Set a breakpoint on line: Range("B1").Activate. And monitor when the code reaches that point. If your computer is "slow" or the sub rutines are complex, then you should notice that is takes a long time to reach that line.

Comment: What is the value of "Run_Times"? What are in all those macros you call - could they be the cause of delays? Check out how and why to avoid `Select`/`Activate` (a search in this site will bring up plenty of discussion). Fully qualify your ranges - are you sure you are getting the values you think you are?

Comment: The macros are running an api and getting data from a trading site, then depending on what trades went off they get manipulated and reversed and sent back to the trading site.

Comment: Run_Times is just a way of setting how many times the program runs depending on what is in cell B2, controls how many times the loop runs before checking on time.